# how to do basic CPI another program from our program?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, cpi, bubblegum

I've read solana and anchor's documentation on doing CPI, but still don't really understand.

what is the basis that must be understood when doing CPI program?

for example I want to call function function from metaplex bubblegum like CreateTree instruction.

but I still fail in trying to understand it.

```
use {
    anchor_lang::prelude::*,
    mpl_bubblegum::{
        ID as BUBBLEGUM_PROGRAM_ID,
        program::Bubblegum,
    }
};

declare_id!("...");

#[program]
pub mod solanacomic {
    use super::*;

    pub fn ping(ctx: Context<PingContext>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Pong!");

        msg!("Calling the bubblegum program... {} | {}", ctx.accounts.bubblegum_program.key(), BUBBLEGUM_PROGRAM_ID);

        invoke(
            mpl_bubblegum::cpi::create_tree(
                CpiContext::new(
                    ctx.accounts.bubblegum_program.to_account_info(),
                ),
                // ...
            ),
            &[
                // ...
            ],
        );

        Ok(())
    }
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct PingContext<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub bubblegum_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up different interfaces here. The `invoke` function is used when the program you're calling isn't an Anchor program and so doesn't implement the CpiContext pattern.

`Invoke` takes two parameters: An `Instruction` and then an accountInfo slice(`&[ // ... ]`). Here it looks like bubblegum has an Anchor-CPI interface so you don't need any of that.

CPI helper functions always take a `CpiContext` as their first argument. Whether or not they take others depends on the implementation of that particular function. Check the definition of `mpl_bubblegum_cpi::create_tree()` to see what extra args it requires if any.

The CpiContext argument is constructed with a CpiContext::new() function which takes two arguments: The first is the account-info of the program you're calling. The second is a struct instance that contains the accounts the CPI instruction needs. The struct type is also provided by the interface and can be imported.

For this particular case I'm guessing [this](https://docs.rs/mpl-bubblegum/0.7.0/mpl_bubblegum/struct.CreateTree.html) is what you need. Construct an instance of it and pass it to CpiContext::new().

Keep in mind that the accounts will need to also be passed from your client to `PingContext` just like the bubblegum program, so they can be used to populate the struct with the values it needs.

Here's a basic template to follow.

```
whitelist::cpi::create_whitelist(
    CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.whitelist_program.to_account_info(),
        CreateWhitelist {
            authority: ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(),
            whitelist: ctx.accounts.whitelist.to_account_info(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        }),
)?;
```

Comment: thanks. your explanation is very easy to understand and I immediately realized my mistake. thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: You're very welcome